# what's the adequate solution for this app

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to develop a app to collect data and export it to a file like a database dump or a text file.

My question is, should I do it as a true android app (with layouts and etc) or can I run a local web page, like a webview with js (if it's possible) and export all data as a json file or similar ?

So what's you guys recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For speed I'd go with native app,
but if you're not too familiar with making Android apps it might be useful to do it with a webview until you finish the native app.